# When I click on edit page in mysite I can not see any tools

Tags: my-site

I have full access and in the site collection, I'm the primary administrator.  The main site is working fine and they both share the same web application.
The page drops as if the tools are there but the area is blank.
any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by "the page drops as if the tools are there"?  Do you mean you go into Site Actions, Edit Page or something else?

Comment: Thats waht I mean, when you click on Edit page, the ribbon space appears but there are no tools available.

Answer (score 1):

Is anonymous access enabled? Anonymous users can see the ribbon but not the tools. Try to sign in and then the problem should be fixed (if this is the problem of course)